# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-addons-update' in 'E:\Redux\calc\src'

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have worked in ReactJS. I have found this error while Mutate a copy of data without changing the original source.

I have imported the **update** from **'react-addons-update'**:

[image]

Still it throws above error.

Comment: Can you verify if you have `react-addons-update` available in `node_modules` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**react-addons-update** be replaced by **immutability-helper**? Apparently, Facebook is deprecating react-addons-update.

The **solution** is found myself:

> npm install immutability-helper --save

Also, update import update replaced in code with :

> import update from 'immutability-helper';